# Regression analysis not showing summary

Tags: r, time-series, regression

The following is my data

```
> x
          day  sum
1  2015-04-14  129
2  2015-04-15  129
3  2015-04-16  129
4  2015-04-17  899
5  2015-04-18  899
6  2015-04-19  899
7  2015-04-20  899
8  2015-04-21  899
9  2015-04-22  899
10 2015-04-23  899
11 2015-04-24  899
12 2015-04-25  899
13 2015-04-26  899
14 2015-04-27  899
15 2015-04-28  899
16 2015-04-29  899
17 2015-04-30  899
18 2015-05-01  899
19 2015-05-02  899
20 2015-05-03  899
21 2015-05-04  899
22 2015-05-05  899
23 2015-05-06  899
24 2015-05-07  899
25 2015-05-08  899
26 2015-05-09  899
27 2015-05-10  899
28 2015-05-11  899
29 2015-05-12  920
30 2015-05-13  920
31 2015-05-14  920
32 2015-05-15  920
33 2015-05-16  920
34 2015-05-17  920
35 2015-05-18  920
36 2015-05-19  920
37 2015-05-20  920
38 2015-05-21  920
39 2015-05-22  920
40 2015-05-23  920
41 2015-05-24  920
42 2015-05-25  920
43 2015-05-26  920
44 2015-05-27  920
45 2015-05-28  920
46 2015-05-29  920
47 2015-05-30  920
48 2015-05-31  920
49 2015-06-01 1076
```

I wanted to do a regression analysis to find out the data at which the sum would become 6000. I did the following,

```
> q<-lm(day ~ sum, data=x)
> q

Call:
lm(formula = day ~ sum, data = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          sum  
  1.653e+04    3.584e-02  

> as.Date(predict(q, data.frame(sum=6000)))
           1 
"2015-11-08"
```

I am able to predict the dates. But I am not sure of the accuracy and want to improve it. But I am not able to view the summary of the regression. I get the following error,

```
> summary(q)
Error in Ops.difftime((f - mean(f)), 2) : 
  '^' not defined for "difftime" objects
```

Just in case, the variable types matter,

```
> typeof(x)
[1] "list"
> typeof(x$day)
[1] "double"
> typeof(x$sum)
[1] "integer"
> class(x$day)
[1] "Date"
```

When I had a look at a previous forum,

[Difftime Error using Looping Regressions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931279/difftime-error-using-looping-regressions-in-r)

The following was given as solution,

I solved this by changing the index from time values to a standard integer index, and everything ran fine.

But I am not sure how to do this?

Can anybody help me with this and say what I need to do to get the summary here?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dates in `R` are actually just numeric values recast into a date format according to certain rules. For example, `Date` format is the number of days elapsed since Jan 1, 1970 and `POSIXct` format is the number of seconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970 referenced to the UTC time zone. Here are a few examples:

```
as.numeric(as.Date("1970-01-01", tz="UTC"))
# 0
as.numeric(as.Date("1970-01-05", tz="UTC"))
# 4
as.numeric(as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"))
# 0
as.numeric(as.POSIXct("1970-01-05 00:00:00", tz="UTC"))
# 345600
```

One way to deal with your problem is to convert the dates to a numeric format, run the regression on the numeric data, and then convert back to date at the end.

In the code below, I've assumed `x$day` starts out in `POSIXct` format.

```
# Convert POSIXct date to a numeric value equal to number of days since Jan 1, 1970
x$day.numeric = as.numeric(x$day)/(24*60*60)

# Regression model
q <- lm(day.numeric ~ sum, data=x)

summary(q)

Call:
  lm(formula = day.numeric ~ sum, data = x)

Residuals:
  Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-22.253 -10.253   1.747   9.994  20.994 

Coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.653e+04  8.448e+00 1956.996  < 2e-16 ***
  sum         3.584e-02  9.550e-03    3.753  0.00048 ***
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 12.67 on 47 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2306,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2142 
F-statistic: 14.09 on 1 and 47 DF,  p-value: 0.0004796

# Predict date at which sum = 6000. Use as.Date to convert numeric value
# back to a date based on the number of days since Jan 1, 1970.
as.Date(predict(q, data.frame(sum=6000)), origin="1970-01-01")
           1 
"2015-11-08"
```

Comment: Cool.. Thanks a lot!! It worked. Just a question out of this context, do you know any ways we can improve the regression analysis?