# R error when calculating the linear regression and p-value of data

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the p-value associated with the linear regression. However, I am getting an error that I don't quite understand.

Here is an example dataset:

```
data <- structure(list(sample_date = structure(c(10382.5, 10549.5, 10737.5, 
10905.5, 11094.5, 11264.5, 11632.5, 11998.5, 12370.5, 12731.5, 
13283.4722222222, 16239.6423611111, 16616.3819444444, 16972.5972222222, 
17337.4506944444, 17695.6041666667, 18011.4479166667, 18380.5618055556, 
18747.0777777778), class = "Date"), sys_loc_code = c("OBA-10A", 
"OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", 
"OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", 
"OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", "OBA-10A", "OBA-10A"
), chemical_name = c("1,1-Dichloroethene", "1,1-Dichloroethene", 
"1,1-Dichloroethene", "1,1-Dichloroethene", "1,1-Dichloroethene", 
"1,1-Dichloroethene", "1,1-Dichloroethene", "1,1-Dichloroethene", 
"1,1-Dichloroethene", "1,1-Dichloroethene", "1,1-Dichloroethene", 
"1,1-Dichloroethene", "1,1-Dichloroethene", "1,1-Dichloroethene", 
"1,1-Dichloroethene", "1,1-Dichloroethene", "1,1-Dichloroethene", 
"1,1-Dichloroethene", "1,1-Dichloroethene"), result_numeric = c(165, 
250, 100, 225, 250, 250, 210, 50, 100, 75, 0.09, 7.5, 6, 6, 0.25, 
0.65, 0.115, 0.115, 0.115)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -19L), groups = structure(list(
    sys_loc_code = "OBA-10A", chemical_name = "1,1-Dichloroethene", 
    .rows = structure(list(1:19), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Here is my code:

```
out <- data %>%
dplyr::group_by(sys_loc_code, chemical_name) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    n = n(),
    Linear_Regression = lm(sample_date~result_numeric)$coefficients[2],
    Linear_Regression_pvalue = summary(lm(sample_date~result_numeric))$coefficients[4],
    MK_Tau = Kendall::MannKendall(result_numeric)$tau,
    MK_2sidedP = Kendall::MannKendall(result_numeric)$sl,
    MK_Score = Kendall::MannKendall(result_numeric)$S,
    MK_denominator = Kendall::MannKendall(result_numeric)$D,
    MK_varS = Kendall::MannKendall(result_numeric)$varS,
  )
```

Here is my error:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `Linear_Regression_pvalue`.
i `Linear_Regression_pvalue = summary(lm(sample_date ~ result_numeric))$coefficients[4]`.
x '^' not defined for "difftime" objects
i The error occurred in group 1: sys_loc_code = "OBA-10A", chemical_name = "1,1-Dichloroethene".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing?  Or know what this error means?

Thanks!

Comment: [Related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170512/regression-analysis-not-showing-summary) I think.

Comment: Thanks - I was worried it somehow had to do with the datetime.  Solved my problem!